# External Webhook Issues - Authentication Error

Tags: azure-blob-storage, webhooks

I read through the answers listed on here and none of them addressed my concern.

When I generate the SAS in Storage Explorer it works well inside of the emulator. When I give that SAS to a customer so they can upload a file, I get an authentication error. The web hook doesn't work outside of storage explorer

The  error states that

Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

The  continues on to say

Signature did not match. String to sign used was

Any advice on how I can get that webhook to work for my client?

I tried to generate the SAS in Storage Explorer. I was expecting the link that worked in the Emulator to work on the web. The clock is not the issue as my allowed window has not expired

Answer (score 0):

Login into Azure portal >> Create Storage Account >> Create Container
[image]

Click on upload file >> Browse for file >> upload
[image]

Once file is uploaded > Change access level permission > Container
[image]

Click on > Share access tokens > Provide permission >
[image]

Click on > Generate SAS Token and URL
[image]

Download azure storage explorer for windows> click on storage account and services.
[image]

Select connection as SAS>
[image]

Copy paste generated > SAS URL in next tab> get connected to your SAS access > Blob Container > Container file > you can perform your activity here.
[image]

Other method connection via Emulator > connect to azure Storage > next >
[image]

Install https://aka.ms/storageexplorer/emulatorusagelearnmore and you can perform your activity Successfully.
[image]

2. To create an SAS token that is usable outside of Storage Explorer, you can alternatively try using the Azure Storage REST API directly. An [example](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/communication-services/tutorials/includes/hmac-header-python.md) Python application that uses the Azure Storage REST API to create an SAS token.

   import hmac
   import base64
   import hashlib
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta

**Replace these values with your own**

```
account_name = "<your account name>"  
account_key = "<your account key>"  
container_name = "<your container name>"  
blob_name = "<your blob name>"  
permission = "rw"  
start_time = datetime.utcnow()  
expiry_time = start_time + timedelta(hours=1)
```

**Construct the canonicalized resource string.**

```
resource = f"/{account_name}/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
```

**Construct the string to sign**

```
string_to_sign = f"{permission}\n{start_time.isoformat()}Z\n{expiry_time.isoformat()}Z\n{resource}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

**Generate the signature**

```
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(account_key), string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
```

**Construct the SAS token.**

```
sas_token = f"{resource}?sv=2021-08-01&st={start_time.isoformat()}Z&se={expiry_time.isoformat()}Z&sp={permission}&sig={signature}"

print(sas_token)
```

Reference [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/how-to-guides/create-sas-tokens?tabs=Containers) [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows).